# 2004 Dodge Ram 1500 Belt Squeal/Chirp

Tags: dodge, serpentine-belt

I have a 2004 Dodge Ram 1500 5.7L Hemi with 4WD. For over a year, I have been trying to get rid of the belt squeal/chirp. I say both because I have experienced both the squeal and the chirp. This all started a week after getting my alternator replaced (mechanics checked the new alternator and said it was fine...but I wonder if there is something going on with the pulley?).

I replaced the belt. It went away for 2 weeks and then came back. I replaced the belt and belt tensioner and it went away for a week, then the squeal came back. I replaced the belt again and it went away for 4 days and came back.  My mechanics discovered my radiator was leaking and spraying on the belt but it took a while to figure out since it was only leaking under pressure. I had the radiator replaced, they replaced the bad idle pulleys, and they cleaned the pulleys and belt really good.  The squeal came back 4 days later. I replaced the belt figuring it was contaminated with coolant, and cleaned the pulleys real well again.  It was quiet for 2 weeks and now a chirp has come.

It doesn't sound when it idles or after I first turn it on and it is warming up and gets louder as I accelerate. I have had the pulleys checked for alignment and supposedly they were good... but I still wonder if it is a pulley problem?  I have  exhausted everything I know how and am clueless and going crazy hearing this chirp.  Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!!